# Spark Anonymous Function

Tags: scala, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have the following spark code

```
val result:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (Int, Int))] = 
      a.join(b,paralelism)
      .map(input:(Int,(Int,(Int,Int)))) => (input._1, input._2._2))     

result.saveAsTextFile(my_hdfs_address_goes_here) 
System.exit(0)
```

Whenever I had the map function as the last operation, I get the following error

```
14/09/19 18:03:04 WARN TaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.lang.ClassCastException

java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of netflix$$anonfun$2 to field 

org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.f of type scala.Function1 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD
```

Any ideas as to how to get rid of it?

Comment: You might want to tell us the types of a and b (just in case) and also make the parentheses match -- something is not quite right on the line with the map.

Comment: Spiro is right, give us more infos :)